Redis lock is stuck on acquiring
I'm trying to perform a sanity check on Redis Locks (async version):
import redis.asyncio as redis
import tqdm
import asyncio

r = redis.Redis(decode_responses=True)


async def update():
    lock = r.lock("lock")
    await lock.acquire(blocking=True)
    k = await r.get("key")
    if int(k) < 0:
        raise ValueError(f"Value {k} is negative")
    await r.setex("key", 3600, -1)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    await r.setex("key", 3600, 1)
    await lock.release()


async def main():
    total = 100
    chunksize = 10
    await r.setex("key", 3600, 1)
    aws = [update() for _ in range(total)]
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=total) as pbar:
        for idx in range(0, total, chunksize):
            end = min(idx + chunksize, total)
            chunk = aws[idx:end]
            await asyncio.gather(*chunk)
            pbar.update(end - idx)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

For some reason, my code doesn't make it past the .acquire step. Am I making any syntax errors?

@user24714692 I actually tried that first. Still doesn't work.
